# iAds still refuse to work

Tags: cocoa-touch, iad

Edit: Here's my AppDelegate as well (part of it)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]];
    GameViewController *gameViewController = [[GameViewController alloc]init];
    NSLog(@"NSLOG %@", [[gameViewController view]class]);
    _bannerViewController = [[BannerViewController alloc]initWithContentViewController:gameViewController];

    self.window.rootViewController = _bannerViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

I am about to give up. I have tried 5 different ways just these past few days to get literally one single iAd to show correctly and as simple as Apple makes it seem, literally 100% of the time I either see no ad or get an error. I have followed the Apple documentation **EXACTLY.**

The only clue I have is in these two lines

```
    GameViewController *gameViewController = [[GameViewController alloc]init];
    NSLog(@"NSLOG %@", [[gameViewController view]class]);
```

Which are in my app delegate. The NSLog gives me "UIView". No. Why? Why would that ever be a UIView, it should be an SKView, because GameViewController was pre-written for me by apple for sprite kit. How could that *possibly* give me the wrong object?

I am getting `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView scene]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x174191780'` which others have recommended to fix by putting the `originalContent` statement but I already have that and it isn't working.

Banner view controller:

```
#import "BannerViewController.h"

NSString * const BannerViewActionWillBegin = @"BannerViewActionWillBegin";
NSString * const BannerViewActionDidFinish = @"BannerViewActionDidFinish";

@interface BannerViewController () <ADBannerViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation BannerViewController {
    ADBannerView *_bannerView;
    UIViewController *_contentController;
}

-(instancetype)initWithContentViewController:(UIViewController *)contentController{
    NSAssert(contentController != nil, @"Attempting to initialize a BannerViewController with a nil contentController.");

    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        _bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithAdType:ADAdTypeBanner];
        _contentController = contentController;
        _bannerView.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)loadView{
    UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]];

//Have also tried SKView *contentView = [[SKView alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]];

    [contentView addSubview:_bannerView];
    [self addChildViewController:_contentController];
    [contentView addSubview:_contentController.view];
    [_contentController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    self.view = contentView;
}
-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation{
    return [_contentController preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return [_contentController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    CGRect contentFrame = self.view.bounds, bannerFrame = CGRectZero;

    bannerFrame.size = [_bannerView sizeThatFits:contentFrame.size];

    if(_bannerView.bannerLoaded){
        contentFrame.size.height -= bannerFrame.size.height;
        bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height;

    }else{
        bannerFrame.origin.y = contentFrame.size.height;
    }

    _contentController.view.frame = contentFrame;
    _bannerView.frame = bannerFrame;
}
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        [self.view setNeedsLayout];
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        [self.view setNeedsLayout];
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
-(BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:BannerViewActionWillBegin object:self];
    return YES;
}
-(void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:BannerViewActionDidFinish object:self];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Game View controller:

```
@interface GameViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *contentView;

@end

@implementation GameViewController {

}
-(instancetype)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    //self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
}
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    SKView *skView = (SKView*)self.originalContentView;
    if (!skView.scene) {
        SKScene *scene = [GameScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];

        [skView presentScene:scene];
        //skView.showsPhysics = YES;


    }

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The answer, as I thought it would be, was incredibly simple and quite mind-boggling that Apple wouldn't put some sort of warning in their documentation, but then again maybe I am just too much of a noob and we are expected to know these kinds of things.

The answer, is that `init` was never being called in `GameViewController`, instead, `initWithCoder:` was being called. Once I `NSLogged` the `init` method and saw it wasn't being called, I figured this out.